# Implementing virtual service marketplace with paypal

Tags: paypal

I need to implement a pretty basic marketplace (users transfer money to other users and a fee is collected with every transaction), i've notice that "adaptive payments" is deprecated. What services should I use?
Should I implement a managed on-boarding?
Should I use adaptive payments?
Any other service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best to go with "PayPal for Marketplaces" or if your marketplace is limited to the US you can use "Braintree Marketplace". Adaptive Payments will probably not be supported forever.